# PHP: Алгоритм расчёта директории исходя и числового значения

Tags: php, математика

Здраствуйте!

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм расчета каталога, состоящий из последовательности цифр.

Директория имеет вид: `/X/Y/Z/` , где X, Y, Z папки, имя которых цифры.

Максимальное количество папок в подпапке равно 5 . Т.е. конечная директория будет : `/5/5/5/`

У меня есть уникальный идентификатор папки. Мне нужно узнать какому пути будет соответствовать цифра, если количество папок в подпапке будет не больше 5-ти. Например, если id папки равен `15`, то путь будет  `0/3/0/`. Для папки 29, путь будет `0/5/4/`, для 32 `1/0/3` и т.д.

Пробую остаток от деления:
Число = 17. Путь рассчитываем делением числа на заданное максимальное количество папок в подпапке. Получается 17/5 = целое число 3, остаток 2. Значит путь будет `0/3/2/`.

Но как рассчитать, если число будет например 37?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$id = 37;
$x = floor($id / 5 / 5);
$y = floor($id / 5 - $x * 5);
$z = $id -  $x * 5 * 5 - $y * 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Я давно не работал с PHP. Но гугл подсказывает, что там есть функция base_convert, которая позволяет преобразовывать между двумя произвольными системами счисления.

Может, вам стоит переводить этой функцией ваше число в пятеричную систему счисления, а результат разобрать на символы?

И кстати, кажется у вас небольшая путаница в условиях задачи. Если цифра "5" в результате допустима, то это уже шестеричная система счисления (пять цифр + ноль) и делить нужно на 6, а не на пять.